# JButton ActionListener not starting TimerTask

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, timertask

I am making a bot for a game that I play, and have made a GUI so the user of the bot has some control over when the bot is active or not. To do this, I made a start/stop button that would set a variable to true. Each attack is a different class, and they extend the TimerTask class. All they have as an implementation of the run() method that TimerTask has, and they just do

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1); //the ".VK_1" part will be different per class
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
```

Ideally, the user would press the button, and TimerTasks would run, simulating keypresses that would be attacks in the game. However, the text on the button does not change, and the TimerTasks never run. Does anyone have a solution for this? My code is below. Thanks in advance!

Main-Class:

```
package AQWGrindBot;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Timer;

public class Main {

    private static boolean playing = false;
    static Timer timer = new Timer();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int speed = 1000;
        final boolean[] startVar = {false};

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AQW Attack Bot");


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,100);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        JButton start = new JButton("START");
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (start.isSelected()) {
                    playing = !playing;
                    if (start.getText().equals("START")) {
                        start.setText("STOP");
                        toggleBot(true);
                    } else {
                        start.setText("START");
                        toggleBot(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(start);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void toggleBot(boolean check) {
        if (check) {
            timer.schedule(new AQWBotATK1(), 0, 1000);
            timer.schedule(new AQWBotATK3(), 0, 3000);
            timer.schedule(new AQWBotATK4(), 0, 17000);
        } else {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S I am on macOS Mojave. I do not know if this is important, but there are apparently some JFrame features that do not work properly on Mac. Please tell me if I am trying to implement one of them. Also, I am using java.awt and the Robot object to simulate key presses.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main problems, the first is here:

```
if (start.isSelected()) {
```

Since `start` is a JButton, `isSelected()` will never be true, and if you want this type of functionality, you should be using a JToggleButton or a JCheckBox or JRadioButton (the latter two which extend from JToggleButton) and which change the selected state on press.

So,

```
JToggleButton start = new JToggleButton("START");
```

Another option is to create your own boolean field to toggle and to test on button press, but then you don't get a visual feed back from the button as to its state. You could also I suppose use the state of the button's text, obtained via `getText()`

Your other problem is your use of a `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` as this creates code that is potentially not Swing thread-safe. It's almost always better to use `javax.swing.Timer` or a "Swing Timer" when creating timers for Swing GUI's since the code within the timer's ActionListener is guaranteed to be called on the Swing event thread.